# Efficient technique or existing tool to align faces at 90 degree angle?

Tags: modeling

I'm looking for an efficient technique or tool that will allow a user to select a face, then select a connected face and quickly set that second face at 90 degrees from the first face (rotated from the connecting edge.)

Use case:

Let's say I've sculpted and then retopologized a mesh intended to be a hard surface helmet. The helmet itself is all curvy, but on the side of the helmet, I have what is supposed to be an extruded rectangular shape, but because it was derived from a sculpt, none of the angles are precise (and none of the faces are intended to be aligned with the object itself or the world orientation).

I want to be able to adjust that rectangular shape efficiently so that all the faces of this extruded rectangle are all 90 degrees from the adjoining faces.

Does this kind of tool exist already or is there an efficient workflow that would allow for setting all connected faces of the rectangle at 90 degrees from each other?

- One technique I am aware of, but doesn't seem super efficient, is setting a custom transform orientation based on the initial face (or set of faces). This sets the orientation for the rectangle. And then selecting the adjoining faces (or set of faces) and scaling them down to 0 along the perpendicular axis of each.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122115/how-to-change-angle-between-two-faces-of-an-object